# How to fix "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a music app using tkinter and python, but I am not able to get rid of "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" bug. Have a look at my code and you'd be much clear with what I am dealing.

The mechanism is pretty simple, I, at first, display the song options via dictionary(list), and after taking the input, corresponding value of "j",(example, if input is 1 then j is one and corresponding value of j is i) to be saved as the name of the song and execute the program by playing the music.

```
list = {
    '1':'Say You Won t Let Go.mp3','2':'In the Jungle the mighty jungle.mp3'
}
lost = ''
print(list)
print("which one?")
this_one = int(input(''))
for j,i in list:
    if j == this_one:
        lost = i
```

Comment: Use `list.items()` instead of `list`. As a side note avoid using `list` as a variable name; it overwrites a builtin type.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `tkinter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: Another (unrelated) thing to be aware of: you're parsing the user input to an int, but the keys in your dictionary are strings so they'll never match.

Comment: also, the whole idea to use dict is to get the value without the need to iterate over keys. You can use `dict.get()` method to handle for missing key.

Comment: Hey, Holloway, thank you. Yes, I figured that out right about now. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,

```
songs = {"1": "Say You Won t Let Go.mp3",
         "2": "In the Jungle the mighty jungle.mp3"}
lost = ''
print(songs)
this_one = int(input("Which One? "))

for number, song in songs.items():
    if number == this_one:
        lost = song
```

`dict.items()` returns a tuple of 2 objects, (Keys, values).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `list.items()`

```
for i, j in list.items():
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with `items()` as you are traversing over `dict`

```
for j,i in list.items():
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to programming. Really appreciate your help.